# Minimize distance between 3 sets of points using numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mathematical-optimization

Given 3 sets of 2-dimensional points `A`, `B` and `C`

```py
A = np.asarray([a1, a2, a3, ..., ak])
B = np.asarray([b1, b2, b3, ..., bm])
C = np.asarray([c1, c2, c3, ..., cn])
```

I want to compute a matrix `AC` of dimensions `k x n` which contains the minimum (euclidean) distance from each point in A to each point in C going through *the best* point in B (the best is such that minimizes the distance of the path `a -> b -> c`)

So far I have the distance matrices `AB` and `BC` with each pair-wise distances between points in A to B, and B to C

```py
AB = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(A, B)
BC = scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(B, C)
```

I could now, of course, run a nested *for loop* to get the matrix `AC`

My question is whether this can be done using only matrix operations between `AB` and `BC` (shape transformations allowed)
It could even be operations between `A`,`B` and `C` directly

Furthermore, is it possible to get a similar matrix `BestB` of dimensions `k x n` which contains at each element `i,j` the *index* of the point in B which minimizes the distance between `A[i]` to `B[j]`?

If there is any efficient algorithm to solve this problem I would also appreciate if you could mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use broadcasting here:

```
dist_mat = (AB[...,None] + BC)
min_dist = dist_mat.min()
```

Comment: Good solution, you may also want `dist_mat.min(axis=2)` and `dist_mat.argmin(axis=2)` to get all of the minimums (for each member of A x C) and the indices which make the minimization

Comment: This worked just as expected! Good to also learn about the possibility of using ellipsis and `None` to slice an array. Thanks!